# JavaScript Intellisense in TypeScript File

Tags: javascript, intellisense, typescript

Is it only possible to get intellisense in TypeScript files by referencing `.ts` files with own coded interfaces?

Is there a solution for existing JavaScript libraries?

Comment: Hopefully there will be, but as of right now, I don't think there are any.

Comment: Is there anything new on using JS Intellisense in TS files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are able to get IntelliSense for other TypeScript files by using an external script reference directive at the top of your script:

```
///<reference path="someOtherScript.ts" />
```

As a side note, the TypeScript IntelliSense reference directive doesn't support the tilde operator like the JavaScript reference directive does. For example, if your script is located in "~/Scripts/foo/", in JavaScript you can reference:

```
///<reference path="~/Scripts/otherScriptFile.js" />
```

whereas in TypeScript you have to reference relative to the current file:

```
///<reference path="../otherScriptFile.ts" />
```

More info about this can be found in section 11.1.1 Source Files Dependencies of the [TypeScript Spec](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf).

With regard to JavaScript IntelliSense in a TypeScript file, it currently appears to be not possible to get JavaScript reference IntelliSense.

Comment: Is there anything new on using JS Intellisense in TS files?

Answer (score 6):

As others before me have pointed out, you need the definition files.

The [DefinitelyTyped GitHub repository](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) provides an excellent (and growing) list of definition files for a lot of popular libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get intellisense support for every JS code (quality may vary), however the typescript specific stuff is only available when using apropriate definition files (*.d.ts).

You can find additional definition files in the source repository (> typings, currently only jQuery and WinJS/RT) http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest